# Is socketio good to use in production website

Tags: javascript, java, php, node.js, socket.io

I want to do some real-time operations in my backend. In the past, I used the pusher for real-time operations. But its cost is huge. So, I am thinking about using the socket IO itself. Before using it, I thought about asking for it in the stackoverflow community. So, what do you guys suggest? Is it suitable for use on a production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.io is already used in production by many big companies for products including [Trello](https://blog.trello.com/the-trello-tech-stack#:%7E:text=We%20use%20a%20modified%20version,of%20CPU%20or%20memory%20usage.), [Microsoft Office, Yammer, and Zendesk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO).

As @Tintin said, it's also very popular on GitHub and NPM.

Answer (score 1):

[Socket.io on Github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) has:

- 56.2k stars
- 1.6k watching
- 10k forks

[On npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io), it shows more than **4.5 million** weekly downloads.

So yeah, I would say a pretty solid choice for production, provided, as with any software, you use it wisely.